# Can I have a textarea field which isn't rich text?

Tags: fieldtypes, richtext

I have a rich text field that I don't want wrapped in anything.

I just want a text area field, but I'm not sure how to get a text area without making it rich text, as the only multiline text field is the rich text field.

If it is going to be rich text, I need to be able to remove wrapping tags and control those.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If what you want is a multi-line plain text field, then check the *Allow line breaks* checkbox for that field.

Comment: Does a plain text field wrap your text only? Because it doesn't seem to generate <br> tags.

Comment: You will want to use twig's [nl2br](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/nl2br.html) filter to change the newlines (in the text field) to <br> tags